# how to use sumif to match multiple criteria on same range

Tags: criteria, libreoffice-calc

how to use sumif to sum up multiple criteria on same range?

i use the formula =sumif(C3:C7,{"A","B","C"},D3:D7), it was able to sum-up only "A".
Even through =sum(sumif(C3:C7,{"A","B","C"},D3:D7)) does not work as well as shown in this screenshot [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMIF(C3:C7;"A";D3:D7)+SUMIF(C3:C7;"B";D3:D7) +SUMIF(C3:C7;"C";D3:D7)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(C3:C7;{"A";"B";"C"};D3:D7))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D3:D7;(C3:C7="A")+(C3:C7="B")+(C3:C7="C"))
```